# using nodejs with pattern matching in CQL

Tags: cassandra, nodes, cql

```
const query= 'SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE "partitionId" =  \'sr\' AND "name" LIKE \'%?%\'';



db.execute(query, ['B']).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I was not able to select data based on the pattern specified in the array.What is the exact way using CQL pattern matching with nodejs.I am getting "Invalid amount of bind variables" error.

NOTE: db has all the connection parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use following instead

```
const query= 'SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE "partitionId" =  \'sr\' AND "name" LIKE ?';
db.execute(query, ['%B%']).then(function(res) {
...
```

P.S. Do you have [corresponding indices](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html) built that support the `LIKE` expression? Cassandra doesn't work the same way as "standard" SQL databases.